# React recompose componentFromStream update not triggers

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, recompose

I have Rx `Observable` from `interval` and another observable from react prop, I did merge with `withLatestFrom` both Observables to listen update and render stream component with `recompose`, its working fine but issue is its not updating when i change the prop to `local` to `utc`.

You can try with increase interval and try to change the LOCAL/UTC button, its not triggering, but its update only when time changes.

[working demo with code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eseekv?file=Hello.js)

```
const locale$ = prop$.pipe(p => p)
  const timeInterval$ = prop$.pipe(
    switchMap(({intervalTime}) => interval(intervalTime)),
    withLatestFrom(locale$, (b, c) => {
    return c.locale === 'local' ? moment().format('HH:mm:ss') : moment().utc().format('HH:mm:ss')
  })//.pipe(map(p => p))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

### What you are looking for is **[combineLatest](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest)** (not **[withLatestFrom](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/withLatestFrom)**).

#### withLatestFrom

Combines the source with another observable (or more!) into an observable emitting arrays with latest values of each, **only when the source emits**.

#### combineLatest

Combines multiple observables into an observable that emits an array with the latest values of each source, **every time one of these observables emits**.

This is the example for combineLatest:

```
const firstTimer = timer(0, 1000); // emit 0, 1, 2... after every second, starting from now
const secondTimer = timer(500, 1000); // emit 0, 1, 2... after every second, starting 0,5s from now
const combinedTimers = combineLatest(firstTimer, secondTimer);
combinedTimers.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
// Logs
// [0, 0] after 0.5s
// [1, 0] after 1s
// [1, 1] after 1.5s
// [2, 1] after 2s
```